# DateTime format gives errors

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a date however it keeps on giving error and have no idea hwat I do wrong.

```
//December 19, 2014 1:21 PM
DateTime logDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anybody can tell me how to do this?

Comment: hh is for two digits hours

Comment: What is the outcome you are getting? and what is the outcome you are wanting?

Comment: If you get an erreur it is helpful to include the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime logDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The issue is single digit `hour`, whereas in your format you are specifying `hh` which is for double digit hour.

If you are expecting single/double digit hour, minute, and day part then you can use:

```
DateTime logDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "MMMM d, yyyy h:m tt",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

single `d`, `h` and `m` would parse both single and double digit values.

You may also see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For this particular date, you can use `DateTime.Parse` as well as the format is available under default `DateTime` formats.

```
DateTime logDate = DateTime.Parse(_date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: And I'll add, `ParseExact` does what it says on the tin. If you *can't* guarantee a match between your input date and the specified format, you may want `DateTime.Parse` instead.

Comment: Thx Habib been busy with this for 3 hours)))

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of  parse exact. If it fails it won't throw an exception in your program and you can check if it's valid or not before you proceed in your code.

Comment: @user3763117, you are welcome, You may also look at `DateTime.TryParseExact` as `prospector` said ^^.

Comment: I second the `TryParse...` series of methods; unless it's a drop-dead error to get an unparseable value, these let you handle the situation a little more gracefully. (For example, if the value is user input, one should always handle the case where the value is unparseable.)